# Meteor js localization

Tags: localization, meteor

I got a meteor app and I want to support multiple languages.
How to support multy language app with meteor js?
Is there a recommended pattern, couldn't find stuff in documentation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Meteor suggest you don't write your own packages at the moment and their appears not to be a bundled l10n package as part of the project.

Two projects worth looking at for server side patterns in Node are [i18n-node](https://github.com/mashpie/i18n-node) and [node-polyglot](https://github.com/ricardobeat/node-polyglot).

Both these projects use simple JSON structures loaded from locale directories and both create new translation keys when you first use them. If you need to create a JSON language pack from an existing source, you could use my [PO->JSON converter](http://localise.biz/free/converter/po-to-json).

**UPDATE**: 
I just found this [Meteor wrapper for i18next](https://github.com/ckir/i18next-meteor/)